# No route matches [GET] "/app1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, get, routes

Rails.root: /home/chris/rails_projects/app1

I get the message about routes. my routes.rb files show:

I do not know how to approach this at all.  I am using Ubuntu 12.04 in Virtualbox.

Rails.application.routes.draw do

```
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # root 'welcome#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a controller and a view to direct your app somewhere.

Then you need to route your app to that action by editing your routes file.  For example you can uncomment the line:

```
 root 'welcome#index'
```

This will then mean that when you navigate to the root of your site at the root directory (/app1) will go to the welcome controller, to its index action.

To learn more, have a look at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root

Comment: Error is `No route matches [GET] “/app1”` so it's not about root route also in a new application if you don't have any root route then rails 4 has default root route, checkout http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#hello-rails-bang :)

Answer (score 0):

[**Routes**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root)

You need to define the routes your application will use, as follows:

```
#config/routes.rb
root 'application#index'
```

This will direct any of the "homepage" traffic to the following controller/action:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def index
   end
end
```

--

**Routing in Rails**

You have to remember that Rails is an [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)-centric web application framework

This means every time you wish to access a "url", you need to define the "route" in your `routes.rb` file. The way to do this is to reference the relevant `controller#actions` in your routes file - using the [`resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) method:

```
#config/routes.rb
root "application#index"
resources :controller_1, :controller_2
```

As Rails is [object-orientated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), the `routes` of your application will generally have to reflect the various *resources* it has inside. Most people try and define routes based on the presumed "flow" of the app - the truth is that you want to construct them *around objects*, which typically means controller and/or models